# Using dask to import many MAT files into one DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, dask

I have many mat files of the same format and I wish to join these mat files into one DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex. Currently, a for loop reads in these mat files and load the contents of each into a pandas DataFrames using scipy.io.loadmat and then each DataFrame is appended to an hdf5 table.

Each mat file contains a 4096x1024 single precision matrix and initally each iteration of the loop takes approximately 1.5 seconds. I have tested this with 806 mat files ( 12.5GB taking ~25 minutes ) but I would like to apply this to potentially millions of these files and I am interested in finding a workflow and data container that would allow me to import new data and query subsets of the time series quickly.

Would it be possible using dask or another tool to speed up this import process and create a single queryable time series?

```
for rot_file in rotation_files:
    print(rot_file)
    time_stamps = pd.DataFrame(scipy.io.loadmat(rot_file)['LineInfo'][0][0][2][0])
    polar_image = pd.DataFrame(scipy.io.loadmat(rot_file)['PolarImage'])
    polar_image = polar_image.transpose()
    polar_image.index = time_stamps[0].apply(convert_to_python_datetime).values
    rot_id = time_stamps[0]
    rot_id_df = pd.DataFrame(len(polar_image)*[rot_id],columns=['rotation_id'], dtype='category')
    rot_id_df.index = polar_image.index
    polar_image.join(rot_id_df)
    polar_image.columns = [str(col_name) for col_name in polar_image.columns]
    polar_image.to_hdf('rot_data.h5', 'polar_image', format='table', append=True, complib='blosc', complevel=9)
```

It seems like the import should be possible using dask.delayed but I am not sure how this can be written to a single hdf file.

Comment: Don't just link to your code externally, please edit it into your post.

Comment: Yes it would be possible. Particularly if you know the number of .mat in advance, you could preallocate an hdf5 table with as many rows (fist dimension) as .mat. Use your constant shape (or none if they vary) for the other dimensions.

Comment: Question: is the purpose to query all the data in the .mat files or to create the hdf data-set?

Comment: The purpose is to query all the data, to be able to extract subsets easily by using a date-based index. It doesn't necessarily have to be in hdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to query the data, you don't need to write to a data format explicitly supported by dask. You could define your dataframe as follows:

```
def mat_to_dataframe(rot_file):
    time_stamps = pd.DataFrame(scipy.io.loadmat(rot_file)['LineInfo'][0][0][2][0])
    polar_image = pd.DataFrame(scipy.io.loadmat(rot_file)['PolarImage'])
    polar_image = polar_image.transpose()
    polar_image.index = time_stamps[0].apply(convert_to_python_datetime).values
    rot_id = time_stamps[0]
    rot_id_df = pd.DataFrame(len(polar_image)*[rot_id],columns=['rotation_id'], dtype='category')
    rot_id_df.index = polar_image.index
    polar_image.join(rot_id_df)
    polar_image.columns = [str(col_name) for col_name in polar_image.columns]
    return polar_image

from dask import delayed
import dask.dataframe as dd

parts = [delayed(mat_to_dataframe)(fn) for fn in matfiles_list]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
```

This is a "lazy" data-frame: you can apply pandas-like computations to it, but these only execute when you call `.compute()`. If the matload process holds the python GIL, then I would recommend using the distributed scheduler (even on a single machine) `client = dask.distributed.Client()`.

If you can know the timestamps of each section a priori, then you can also provide `divisions=` to `from_delayed`, which means that if your queries have filters on the index, then dask will know which files don't need to be loaded.

If the process to load is slow, and you want a faster format to query from, try `df.to_hdf` or `df.to_parquet`. Each have several options that will affect your performance.

Note that `time_stamps[0].apply(convert_to_python_datetime).values` can probably be achieved faster using `pd.to_datetime(time_stamps[0])`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, the time_stamps are NTFS timestamps in 100s of nanoseconds which doesn't appear to be interpreted correctly by to_datetime, [my conversion function is here](https://gist.github.com/seumasmorrison/7c52b44d2cbf4ea9d172e72619bda0c8). I attempted to run to_hdf on the delayed DataFrame, but I think it duplicates some of the records, the hdf file being written has more records than the original files.

Comment: That sounds very odd - if you could produce a minimal reproducible example, it may prove interesting.

Comment: It was my mistake, I accidentally used the %timeit magic instead of %time in the jupyter notebook cell with the call to_hdf so it was repeating the process multiple times. Is there any method in dask where you could get an idea of progress or time to run for a call like to_hdf which takes some time to execute?

Comment: You will want the dask profiler or progress bar, e.g., [this](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html#example) for threaded and [this](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.diagnostics.progress) for the distributed scheduler.